# Move a file, AX2012

Tags: axapta, file-handling, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm trying to move a file, nothing clever.

The problem I am having is explained in the [AX WONDERS blog](http://axwonders.blogspot.com.es/2011/07/workaround-to-exceptionclrerror-using.html).

> The reason for this is that when using an AX class that runs on the server, the exception never comes back to the client and therefore cannot be handled correctly....   the operation will not fall into the Exception::CRLError exception

If the source file is opened by MSWord, for example, an exception is thrown in the *fileLocked* method, which is both infuriating yet amusing.

Any suggestions most welcome!

Some code:

```
server static void moveFile(str fileName, str newFileName)
{
    #File
    Set                 permissionSet;
    ;

    permissionSet =  new Set(Types::Class);
    //permissionSet.add(new FileIOPermission(fileName,#io_write));
    permissionSet.add(new FileIOPermission('',#io_write));
    permissionSet.add(new InteropPermission(InteropKind::ClrInterop));

    CodeAccessPermission::assertMultiple(permissionSet);

    if (isRunningOnServer()) 
    { 
        if (WinAPIServer::fileExists(newFileName))
            WinAPIServer::deleteFile(newFileName);
        WinAPIServer::copyFile(fileName, newFileName);
        if (!WinAPIServer::fileLocked(fileName))
            WinAPIServer::deleteFile(fileName);
    }
    else
    {
        if (WinApi::fileExists(newFileName))
            WinApi::deleteFile(newFileName);
        WinAPI::copyFile(fileName, newFileName);
        if (!WinAPI::fileLocked(fileName))
            WinAPI::deleteFile(fileName);
    }
    //System.IO.File::Move(fileName, newFileName);

    CodeAccessPermission::revertAssert();
}
```

Error registry:

```
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'M:\Interfaces\Prod\ImportacionClientes\Direcciones\XXXXXXAD_20130711_1136.TXT' because it is being used by another process.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)

   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)

   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)

   at System.IO.File.OpenWrite(String path)

   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.WinAPIServer.fileLocked(String _fileName) in WinAPIServer.fileLocked.xpp:line 33

   at Dynamics.Ax.Application.EVE_UlaboxInterfaceClientes_IN.moveFile(String fileName, String newFileName) in EVE_UlaboxInterfaceClientes_IN.moveFile.xpp:line 19
```

Comment: Why the delete, copy, delete thing?

Comment: Just a simple 'Move' would be better, I agree.  But the first delete is to ensure that the destination is free, before copying the file.

Comment: Then do a `System.IO.File::Delete(newFileName);` first. Do not forget to catch  `CLRError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for the

```
 System.IO.File::Move(fileName, newFileName);
```

instead of being to clever. 
Consider the prior existence of the `newFileName` an error.

Don't use the `WinAPI` file methods in a server or batch context (you checked that).
Using both `WinAPI` and `WinAPIServer` is just too painful, go straight for the .Net methods.

Most likely the `fileLocked` is in error.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access the `newFileName` without asserting permissions on it. Moreover, the `isRuningOnServer()` method doesn't work as expected in all cases during batch processing, so I would investigate if it's working fine in your case.

Answer (score 0):

TextIo and the it's base classes don't release the file read lock when used in batch even if you assign the object null.

Rewrite the import with StreamReader and use .close() and .dispose() and it will work.

Edit:
Calling finalize() on TextIo will close the file, also when running in batch.

Answer (score -2):

```
System.IO.File::Move(fileName, newFileName);
```